# What is the meaning of 相邻权？

Tags: translation

I know nothing at all about the law, so I don't know how 相邻权 might be translated in English. ‘neighbours law' doesn't seem very jurisprudent! Any tips please?

近年知识产权案件逐年上升，案件类型也从单纯的著作权，商标权和专利权向其相邻权转变，案件涉及的领域也更加广泛。

After a few rereads, I come to the conlusion '向其相邻权‘ is not a law or a right, it just means '(and) to their related laws' Is that right? I'm a bit slow off the mark this morning!

Comment: The English term is 'related rights'

Comment: 著作权   copyright 商标权  right of trade mark 专利权 patent right 相邻 adjacent；next to；adjacency，neighbouring

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment first, just went straight to edit! Glad you agree!

Answer (score 2):

著作权的"相邻权" is not 'related laws' but 'related rights'. Related laws is 相关的法律。It is not the same as 相邻权 of real estates. I think the Chinese term might be a bit hard to understand, because 相邻 means adjacency not related.

**Chinese definition**

著作权(知识产权)的相邻权或邻接权，是表演者、录音录像制作者和广播企业对其节目、录音录像制品所拥有的权利，这一权利主要通过1961年10月26日的《关于表演者、唱片制作者和广播组织的国际公约》(罗马公约)， 1971年10月29日的《保护唱片制作者防止唱片被擅自复制公约》(唱片公约) 以及1996年12月20日由世界知识产权组织制定的《表演和录音制品条约》进行调整。

**English explanation**

The purpose of related rights is to protect the legal interests of certain persons and legal entities who contribute to making works available to the public; or who produce subject matter which, while not qualifying as works under the copyright systems of all countries, contain sufficient creativity or technical and organizational skill to justify recognition of a copyright-like property right.

From http://www.wipo.int/edocs/pubdocs/en/intproperty/909/wipo_pub_909.pdf (Page 16)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. In your opinion, '相邻权‘ is legalese? For me, in English, 'related rights' just means here 'rights similar to 知识产权，著作权，商标权 or 专利权‘ without specifying the reference more closely. 'related rights' is not a legalese term in English, as far as I am aware. You would have to say to which specific rights you were referring.